# Pyqt5 TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, regex, pyqt5

I need to write a program having a GUI to input a File - shtech1.txt
Then need to open the file and extract lines between

- show vlan

and

- show

and write to another file - **shvlan1.txt**

Below is my program and I am getting error `TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object` on the line:

`if re.match('- show vlan -',line):`

Could someone help me on this

## Code:

```
def on_pushButton_clicked(self): #shtech1
    dialog = QFileDialog(self)
    dialog.exec_()
    for file in dialog.selectedFiles():
        shtech1 = QFile(file)
        shtech1.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        found = False
        copy = False
        shvlan1 = open('shvlan1.txt', 'a')
        while not found:
           line = shtech1.readLine()
           print("line is",line)

           if re.match('- show vlan -',line):
              copy = True
              print ("copy is True")
           elif re.match('- show',line):
              if copy:
                 found = True
                 copy = False
                 print ("copy is False")
              elif copy:
                 shvlan1.write(line)
                 print ("printing")
    shvlan1.close()
    shtech1.close()
```

Getting the below error:

```
File "UImlag.py", line 34, in on_pushButton_clicked
if re.match('- show vlan -',line):
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 160, in match
return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Comment: Improved grammar and code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful when mixing Qt and Python APIs when working with files.

Here's what happens when you read a line using `QFile`:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore
>>> qfile = QtCore.QFile('test.txt')
>>> qfile.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
True
>>> qfile.readLine()
PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'foo\n')
```

So, in Python, it's just like opening a file like this:

```
>>> pfile = open('test.txt', 'rb')
>>> pfile.readline()
b'foo\n'
```

only you end up with a `QByteArray` instead of `bytes`.

The Qt way to open files in text-mode is to use a `QTextStream`:

```
>>> stream = QtCore.QTextStream(qfile)
>>> stream.readLine()
'foo\n'
```

But really, why mess around like that when you can just do this:

```
>>> pfile = open('test.txt')
>>> pfile.readline()
'foo\n'
```

(Just because you are getting a filename from a `QFileDialog` doesn't mean you have to use the Qt APIs to read from it.)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
str(line).decode('utf-8')
```

to turn it into a string that regex handles. You may need to replace with the encoding used by your qt (which is a preference).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting error: AttributeError: 'QByteArray' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: ah, another layer. Edited (but perhaps you can use the method above)